# How to interpret the PCA (fviz_pca_var)?

Tags: pca

I need someone to check on my analysis. I really appreciate if someone can help me... I made the following visualization from my data. The correlation coefficient between "Disch" and "precipitation" in my actual data is very low. However, it looks like to me they are highly correlated in this graph... in other words, does the cosine of the angle between 2 variables show the correlation between them? if so, then my "precipitation" and "disch" should be highly correlated... however, they are not... I am confused.[correlation circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnc8o.png)